# Hibernate: PostgreSQL Driver issue

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate, driver

I know that there are similar questions already, but the answers there didn't help me. So please would you mind to take a look at my particular question?

I am not very experienced with Hibernate yet and hava a problem when trying to create test data for my local database with Hibernate 4.3 and PostgreSQL.

I had another project where I did this exactly the same way and there it worked, so I did exactly the same setup but with another database, but now in my current project I get the following exception:

```
exception.DBException: Could not configure Hibernate!
    at dao.BenutzerDAO.<init>(BenutzerDAO.java:48)
    at export.ExportDBSchema.main(ExportDBSchema.java:16)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.postgresql.Driver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:245)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at dao.BenutzerDAO.<init>(BenutzerDAO.java:45)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.postgresql.Driver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:230)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:242)
    ... 15 more
```

I searched for possible solutions, but none of them worked for me:

-)Specify Classpath to jar in Manifest.mf -> Did not work 
-)Place the postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar in lib folder under WEB-INF -> Did not work 
-)Specify hibernate.cfg.xml file in Configuration().configure(); -> Did not work

I use Glassfish 4.1 and the org.postgres.Driver.class is existing, so why is it not found?

My hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Testdb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <mapping class="entity.Benutzer"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Method in DAO class where the exception occurs:

```
try {
            if (sessionFactory == null) {
                Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure();

                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder
                        = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
                builder.applySettings(conf.getProperties());

                sessionFactory = conf.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new DBException("Could not configure Hibernate!", ex);
        }
```

I would be very thankful for every answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close!

You need to place your `postgresql-<version>.jar` directly in the `lib` folder of your **servlet container**.
For instance, if you're working with *Apache Tomcat*, simply drop your *jar* under `<TOMCAT_ROOT>/lib` and you should be all set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it still throws the exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.postgresql.Driver. I tried to put the jar in every lib folder I could find in my project and server folder but it did not work either

Comment: In the meantime the problem could be solved. It had something to do with the location of the jar but I don't really know what I did different this time, but now it works :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using maven or gradle.

You can add this to ur pom.xml for maven

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And  this for gradle

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql
compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.4'
```